# How to use latest value of a variable in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that counts. The function `showResultAndCount()` shows `counter` and adds 1, the other function `showResult()` just shows `counter`.

I would like both functions to be able to work with the latest value of the variable `counter`. At the moment both functions seem to have their own version of the variable. How can I achieve this without using global variables?

This so elementary I assume it will be a duplicate, but I have no idea how this behaviour is called and therefore have no idea what I should be searching for on stack overflow or Google.

```html
<script>
  function showResultAndCount(counter) {
    let someButton = document.getElementById('counter1');
    someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      counter++;
      alert(counter);
    });
    return counter;
  }

  function showResult(counter) {
    someButton = document.getElementById('counter2');
    someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(counter);
    });
  }
</script>

<button id='counter1'>
  Show counter and count
</button>
<br /><hr />
<button id='counter2'>
  Show counter
</button>

<script>
  let counter = '0';
  counter = showResultAndCount(counter);
  showResult(counter);
</script>
```

Comment: what you are looking for is "global variable" .

Comment: @JonasWilms is it possible to do this without global variables? The sample code is very simple, but I want this to happen in a bigger project where there would be quite a few of those variables and I read that it wasn't a good idea to use too many global variables. I'm sorry, I should have put that in there from the beginning.

Comment: it only has to be global from the functions point of view, it doesnt have to be in the global scope (thats bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do...

Note: It's a good practice to not pollute the global namespace hence the scoping.

```js
(function(){
  let counter = 0;
  
  function showResultAndCount() {
   let someButton = document.getElementById('counter1');
   someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     counter++;
     alert(counter);
   });
  }

  function showResult() {
    someButton = document.getElementById('counter2');
    someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(counter);
    });
  }
  
  showResultAndCount();
  showResult();
  
})();
```

```html
<button id='counter1'>
  click this text to show the counter and count
</button>
<br /><hr />
<button id='counter2'>
  click this text to show the counter
</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! Since i posted this question, the duplicate mark pointed me towards scoping but while I understood what it was, I wasn’t sure how to achieve the desired behaviour in an elegant manner. Thanks for showing me!

Comment: Just wondering, why is the last line of the JS code `})();` and not `}());`?

Comment: Read on Immediately Invoked Function Expression(IIFE). In summary, it immediately calls the enclosing expression. Just like how you call a function, foo();

Answer (score 1):

Try following - do not pass `counter` variable in the function by doing that you are creating separate copies of the variable.

```html
<script>
  function showResultAndCount() {
    let someButton = document.getElementById('counter1');
    someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      counter++;
      alert(counter);
    });
  }

  function showResult() {
    someButton = document.getElementById('counter2');
    someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(counter);
    });
  }
</script>

<button id='counter1'>
  click this text to show the counter and count
</button>
<br /><hr />
<button id='counter2'>
  click this text to show the counter
</button>

<script>
  let counter = 0;
  showResultAndCount();
  showResult();
</script>
```